# Lambda Expression for Many to Many realtionship in C# EF 5 Code First

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, lambda, ef-code-first

I'm using EF 5 Code First and VS 2012.
I have  classes for Articles and Tags. Each Article will have atleast one Tag associated.
Please see the classes below.

```
public class Article
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArticleTag> Tags { get; set; }
}
public class Tag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleTag
{
    public int ArticleId { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }

    // navigation property
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the code I tried. **requestTags** contains the list of TadgIds. **repBase** is db context. But below code is returing all Articles.

```
var idList = requestTags.tags.Select(t => t.id).ToList();
 var result= repBase.GetAll<Article>().Select(tg => tg.Tags.Where(tk => idList.Contains(tk.TagId))).ToList();
```

Please hlep me to get list of articles for a given list of TagIds.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reason for Editing my old question is, I don’t want to find more DownVotes. Reason for opening new question is , Im not sure whether there is chance of reopening closed questions as per the Stackoverflow protocol

Comment: Well I mean, if you had 5 downvotes with the exact same question, you should ask yourself, "what could I change so I don't get 5 downvotes again"

Comment: Thanks for concern. Actually my initial first question was simple two lines. Just asking for Many to Many relation expression with 3 class names (I paid off for not having coffee :) ). My edited question will give complete info I'm looking for.

Comment: Right, I've just read the original unedited question. Sorry!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are looking for this.

Change:

- `Select` to `Where`
- `tg.Tags.Contains` to `tg.Tags.Any`

example:

```
var idList = requestTags.tags.Select(t => t.id).ToList();

var result= repBase.GetAll<Article>().Where(tg => tg.Tags.Any(tk => idList.Contains(tk.TagId))).ToList();
```