# Lambda Expression for Many to Many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

Based on the following Data Model, I want to write a "method syntax" lambda query that gives me a collection of `RoleGroupMaps` for a specific `CMRole` (in CMRoles table) and `UIResource` (in UIResources table).

[image]

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13051330/lambda-expression-for-many-to-many-realtionship-in-c-sharp-ef-5-code-first)
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25218665/using-lambda-expression-for-implementing-a-query-in-many-to-many-relation-tables) but can't get what I need.

Comment: thanks @GrantWinney for edit my post. I end up find UIResourceGroup from a UIResource and can get user roles (CMRoles list) but i cant go further. i think i can do it with a couple if foreach but i dont want go that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assume `urId` is id of specific `UIResource` and `listOfCMRoleIds` is list of specified `CMRole`

```
context.UIResource.Where(x => x.ID == urId)
    .Join(context.UIResourceGroupMaps,
        x => x.ID, x => x.UIResourceID,
        (x, y) => y)
    .Join(context.UIResourceGroups,
        x => x.UIResourceGroupID, x => x.ID,
        (x, y) => y)
    .Join(context.RoleGroupMaps.Join(context.CMRoles.Where(x => listOfCMRolesIds.Contains(x.ID)),
                                   x => x.CMRoleID, x => x.ID,
                                   (x, y) => x),
        x => x.ID, x => x.UIResourceGroupID,
        (x, y) => y);
```

Comment: thanks @HPT, how about if i want to do that all in single lambda query. I mean i hvae a speciefic UIResource and a List of CMRoles as conditions and want RoleGroupMaps as result of query.